# how can i configue handwriting recognition in ABBYY ios sdk

Tags: ios, sdk, ocr, handwriting, abbyy

i have tried ABBYY SDK for ios it is very good for printed text to be converted but i cant recongnize handwritten words can any one help me to configue the ocr ABBYY sdk to recognize the handwriting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ABBYY Mobile OCR SDK does not support handwritten recognition. Though there is handprinted recognition in [ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processTextField/) that can be used from iOS. To select Handprinted use "textType=handprinted" option.